# how to force-refresh the previous page's url when the back button on the browser is pressed after changing it with window.history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a web app where the user can navigate from one page to another without reloading the pages but at the same time updating the url as the content changes. I use jQuery `.load()` function to change the page content and `window.history.pushState()` to change the URL.

```
$(".change-url").on('click', function (e)
{ 
    window.history.pushState('page', 'title', 'about.php');
    $("#page-content").load('about.php');
})
```

When I click the "change-url" button on the *home.php* page to go to the *about.php* page, it works fine and the url changes to *about.php* but when I click the back button on the browser from the *about.php* page, the `#page-content` div still shows *about.php* page content although the url changes correctly back to *home.php*.

Please how can I force the browser to reload the new url (*home.php*) when the back button is pressed? or is there a better way of achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: Anyway you can listen to [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate). Either you can call to refresh or you can fetch _home.php_ the same way you fetch _about.php_

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try